# Magento: How to update Category Name via install script

Tags: magento

How to update Category Name via install script in Magento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install scripts are part of the application so can use the same models as normal.

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
// can alternatively use loadByAtrribute('name', $oldName)

$category->setName($newName)
         ->save();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
//increase the max execution time
@ini_set('max_execution_time', -1);
//memory_limit
@ini_set('memory_limit', -1);

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

// Start Despaly All Product Meta Title And Description
require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                         ->getCollection()
                         // magic is prepared here..
                         ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                         // then the magic happens here:
                         ->addAttributeToFilter('level', array('eq'=>4))
                         ->load();
    if (count($categories) > 0):

        foreach($categories as $category):

            $catId = $category->getId();
            $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId);

            if($catId==1465):
                $CategoryName = $category->getName(); 
                $CategoryNewName = "New Name";

                $category->setName($metaTitle);

                $category->save();



                $check = $category->getName();
                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($check);
                echo "\n";
            endif; 

        endforeach;
     else: echo "No Results";
    endif;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$installer->run("
    UPDATE catalog_category_entity_varchar SET value = '[value]' WHERE value_id = [value_id]
");
```

Answer (score 0):

### Magento 2 category Attribute Value Update by Script with level of the category

```
<?php
    //increase the max execution time
    @ini_set('max_execution_time', -1);
    //memory_limit
    @ini_set('memory_limit', -1);

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');

    use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

    include('app/bootstrap.php');

    $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

    $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        

    $appState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');

    $appState->setAreaCode('frontend');

    $categoryCollection = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');

    $categories = $categoryCollection->create();

    $categories->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $categories->addAttributeToFilter('level', array('eq'=>2));
    $categories->load();

    if (count($categories) > 0):

            foreach($categories as $category):

                $catId = $category->getId();

                $category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory')->create()->setStoreId(0)->load($catId);

                $childrenCategories = $category->getChildrenCategories();

                if(!$childrenCategories->count()) continue;

                    $CategoryName = $category->getName();

                    $category->setLandingPage(82);
                    $category->setDisplayMode("PAGE");
                    $category->save();

                    $checkpage = $category->getLandingPage();
                    $checkmode = $category->getDisplayMode();

                    echo "<pre>";
                    print_r($CategoryName);
                    echo "<pre>";
                    print_r($checkpage);
                    echo "<pre>";
                    print_r($checkmode);

            endforeach;
         else: echo "No Results";
        endif;

    ?>
```